# Tomcat 9.0.36 https configuration to port 8443 not responding

Tags: ubuntu, https, tomcat9

I have a Tomcat 9.0.36 running on a Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (virtual)machine. I am trying to configure it to use a certificate that I got from a CA. I generated successfully the keystore file using keytool, and tried to configure Tomcat to listen on port 8443 for https traffic.

The relating fields in server.xms:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="100"
       scheme="https" secure="true"
       SSLEnabled="true"
       clientAuth="false"
       sslProtocol="TLS"
       keyAlias="correctAlias"
       keystoreFile="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.2/lib/security/keystorefile.jks"
       keystorePass="correctPassWord" />
```

I have tried with multiple configurations of both ports, (with or without redirectPort=..., commented out the other port etc.), and the end result is the same. On port 8080, everything works fine (when connector enabled), but on 8443, the result is:

```
This site can’t be reached {my ip} took too long to respond.
```

netstat -plnt gives followint:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         
tcp   0  0 0.0.0.0:8080    0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      22748/java
tcp   0  0 0.0.0.0:8443    0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      22748/java
...
```

So I assume there is something that prevents server from responding, as catalina.out doesn't give any errors, just the startup information, that http-nio-8080 and http-jsse-nio-8443 have started, and everything seems to be runnig.

I am aiming for the end result to be that everything redirects to the https protocol, and nothing is unencrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the port (8443) is allowed or opened for your IP address.

So that connection can reach from outside world.

Comment: I am working on an internal network, and by default 8080 has been open, so I don't see reason for 8443 not to be. I must consult the network admin if there is something weird going on.

Comment: @Nirmal  How can I check port (8443) is allowed or opened??

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was something interesting going on in our network, so I ended up routing the port 443 to 8443 using

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

This seems to work. In the end, this was what I was after anyways, so I managed to solve two problems at once.

Comment: how can I undo this after routing 443 to 8443??